# a link in nav stays active when it shouldn't in Angular

Tags: angular, hyperlink, routes

I'm having an issue with my angular routing. I have a module called hha-caregivers and I have another one called caregivers, which is located at hha-caregivers/caregivers ( I did this because I created the hha one first, and I wanted to use the same modules.)
Everything works fine, but when I click on the sidenav for caregivers, which has a path of hha-caregivers/caregivers, both hha-caregivers and caregivers are highlighted.
I'm using the Clarity framework on Angular.
This is my app.routing module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { DefaultLayoutComponent } from './layout/default.layout.component';



import {
  AngularFireAuthGuard,
  AuthPipe,
  canActivate,
  customClaims,
  redirectLoggedInTo,
  redirectUnauthorizedTo,
} from '@angular/fire/auth-guard';
import { pipe } from 'rxjs';
import {UsersComponent} from './admin/users/users/users.component';
import {AdminLayoutComponent} from './layout/admin.layout.component';

const adminOnly = () =>
  pipe(
    customClaims,
    map((claims) => {
      // console.log('claims', claims)
      return claims?.role === 'admin';
    })
  );

const redirectUnauthorizedToLogin = () => redirectUnauthorizedTo(['auth']);
const redirectLoggedInToCaregivers = () =>
  redirectLoggedInTo(['/', 'hha-caregivers', 'visits']);

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'hha-caregivers' },

  {
    path: '',
    component: DefaultLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'hha-caregivers',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('./caregivers/caregivers.module').then(
            (m) => m.CaregiversModule,
          ),
        ...canActivate(() => adminOnly()),
        ...canActivate(() => redirectUnauthorizedToLogin()),
      },
    ],
  },
    
  
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { enableTracing: false })],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})

export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

this is my caregivers routing module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { canActivate, redirectUnauthorizedTo } from '@angular/fire/auth-guard';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { VisitsCalendarComponent } from './HhaCaregivers/visits-calendar/visits-calendar.component';
import {CaregiversComponent} from './caregivers/caregivers.component';
import {HhaCaregiversComponent} from './HhaCaregivers/hha-caregivers.component';

const redirectUnauthorizedToLogin = () => redirectUnauthorizedTo(['auth']);

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    component: HhaCaregiversComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'caregivers',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    component: CaregiversComponent,
  },
  { path: 'visits', component: VisitsCalendarComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class CaregiversRoutingModule {}
```

this is my navigation.ts file

```
import { Navigation } from '../models/navigation.interface';

export const navigations: Navigation[] = [
  {
    id: 'hhacaregivers',
    title: 'HHA Caregivers',
    link: ['/', 'hha-caregivers'],
  },
  {
    id: 'caregivers',
    title: 'Caregivers',
    link: ['/hha-caregivers', 'caregivers'],
  },

  {
    id: 'agencies',
    title: 'Agencies',
    link: ['/', 'agencies'],
  },

  {
    id: 'transactions',
    title: 'Transactions',
    link: ['/', 'transactions'],
  },

];
```

this is my sidenav.html file

```
<nav>
  <section class="sidenav-content">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let nav of navigations">
      <a
        class="nav-link"
        *ngIf="!nav?.children?.length"
        routerLinkActive="active"
        [routerLink]="nav.link"
        >{{ nav.title }}</a
      >
      <section *ngIf="nav.children?.length" class="nav-group collapsible">
        <input id="tabexample1" type="checkbox" />
        <label for="tabexample1">{{nav.title}}</label>
        <ul class="nav-list">
          <li>
            <a
              class="nav-link"
              *ngFor="let childNav of nav.children"
              [routerLink]="childNav.link"
              routerLinkActive="active"
              >{{childNav.title}}</a
            >
          </li>
        </ul>
      </section>
    </ng-container>
  </section>
</nav>
```

here's an image of how it looks when caregivers is selected on the sidenav[image]

Comment: see the docs: https://angular.io/guide/router#active-router-links, you should use "[routerLinkActiveOptions]={ exact: true }": `<a
class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLink]="nav.link" [routerLinkActiveOptions]={ exact: true }>....</a>`

Comment: thanks for the source! I couldn't give it a check cuz it's posted as a comment, and not as an answer.